# Find Total Ad Account Adspend - Facebook Graph API Explorer

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth-2.0

I am using the [Facebook Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to try and find the adspend for a specific ad account the user has selected. I'm building a dashboard that pulls in facebook ad spend leveraging the [Marketing insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reporting).

The issue I'm running into this is: How do I allow for the user to choose the ad account they would like to pull data from?

I can easily find all the ad accounts associated to a user via the `/me/adaccounts` endpoint. That returns an object like so:

```
"data": [
    {
      "account_id": "16730431364321",
      "id": "act_16730431312239172"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "181543525843374",
      "id": "act_181738765443374"
    },
    {
      "account_id": "393007654523994",
      "id": "act_01923007974523994"
    }
  ],
```

However, I don't know which of these accounts the user wants. When I tried the "Page Access Token", that prompted the user to select the page they want to give permissions to. However, it appears the Page Access Token is intended for managing Facebook pages and not add accounts.

Reading through the Docs, this looks like the endpoint I want to hit `/{ad-account-id}/insights`. It just begs the question, how do I allow the user to select the ad account the want to pull data from?